# How to define the uniform norm on functions of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

I am unsure on how to apply the uniform norm on the following problem.

> **Exercise 2.10** Let $C_0\big(\mathbb{R}^n\big)$ be the closure of the space $C_c\big(\mathbb{R}^n\big)$ of continuous, compactly supported functions with respect to the uniform norm. Prove that $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n\big)$ is the space of functions that vanish at inifinity.

-*Applied Analysis*, by John K. Hunter.

Setting $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, I take that to mean that $||x||=\max\limits_{i=1,\ldots,n}(x_i)$. What, then is $||f(x)||$? Typically I see the uniform norm represented something like $||f||=\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)|$, for $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$.

Is it
$$\max_{i=1,\ldots,n}|f(x)|$$
or
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\max_{i=1,\ldots,n}|f(x)|?$$

Comment: It is $\|f\| = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} |f(x)|$. I don't know what the $i$ is in your last two equations.

Comment: $\mathbb R^{n}$ is the domain of your functions. not the range.

Comment: @copper.hat, then how do I define $|f(x)|$?.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, then is the range any normed space endowed with some metric $||\cdot||_Y$, so that $||f||=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}||f(x)||_Y$?

Comment: Are you asking how to define the modulus/absolute value?

Comment: In standard terminology you are looking at real or complex valued  functions. Unless otherwsie specified you don't consider normed linear space valued functions.

Comment: Ok, @KaviRamaMurthy, thanks. So, $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$?